# setInterval de 5 segundos travando o navegador

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu estou desenvolvendo aplicações usando jQuery/Ajax e ele tem que atualizar a página de 5 em 5 segundos, ele funciona. Mas se eu começo a usar a aplicação o navegador começa a travar por causa do código, como consertar esse problema?

Segue o código:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
agenda();
});
function agenda() {
        $.post('cadastrados_compromiso.php', {
                mes2: "<?php echo $mes2; ?>",
                mes: "<?php echo $mes; ?>",
                ano: "<?php echo $ano; ?>",
                dia: "<?php echo $dia; ?>",
                semana: "<?php echo $semana; ?>",
                agenda: "<?php echo $agenda; ?>",
                login: "<?php echo $login; ?>"
            }, function(resposta) {
                    $("#mudaragenda").html(resposta);
                    var myVar = setInterval(function(){agenda()},5000);
            }, 'html');

}
</script>
```

Ele trava todos navegadores, acho que começa a bugar pois é muito pouco tempo de atualização e o navegador não aguenta (?)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Experimente trocar sua função `setInterval()` pela função `setTimeout` de forma recursiva.

Por Exemplo:

```
$(MeuAjax); // Inicia seu ajax no DOM
function MeuAjax() {
   $.ajax({ 
      complete: function() {
          // Sua lógica
          setTimeout(MeuAjax, 5000);
      }
   });
}
```

A função `setInterval()` tem um gasto de memória excessivo e desnecessário

Comment: valew, funcionou!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tente trocar sua estrutura para essa:

```
setInterval($.ajax /*referencia para a funcao ajax*/,
 2000, {url: 'suaurl', success: onSuccess, error: onError}/*argumentos passados para o $.ajax*/
);
```

Você também pode trocar o `setInterval()` pelo `http-equiv="refresh"`, porém ele aplica o refresh para a página inteira.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
```